# Unable to install package "quanteda.textstats" in R under Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, package, rstudio

I am trying to install the package <kbd>quanteda.textstats</kbd> in R under Ubuntu Version 22.04.1 LTS.

I initially ran:

```
install.packages("quanteda.textstats")
```

where I got an error message saying it could not install the dependency <kbd>proxyC</kbd>. I was able to install that, but I still get an error message when running the above code.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: quanteda.textstats.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘quanteda.textstats’
* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/quanteda.textstats’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘quanteda.textstats’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpuUtAq1/downloaded_packages’
```

I would guess I am missing certain dependencies, but I am unable to figure out what <kbd>-llapack</kbd> and <kbd>-lblas</kbd> stands for.

I also tried running the github install (option 3):

```
remotes::install_github("quanteda/quanteda.textstats")
```

but there as well I get a similar error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: quanteda.textstats.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘quanteda.textstats’
* removing ‘/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/quanteda.textstats’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpuUtAq1/file17581cc7f39c/quanteda.textstats_0.96.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: How did you install R? It ships with its own versions of blas and lapack libraries; Do oyu maybe need `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` ??  (and these libs are not listed as dependencies of [quanteda.textstats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quanteda.textstats/index.html))

Comment: I installed it with `sudo apt-get install r-base` maybe the leaving out of `-dev` caused the problem?

Comment: Yes, see [the docs](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html); "*Users who need to compile R packages from source [e.g. package maintainers, or anyone installing packages with install.packages()] should also install the r-base-dev package: `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to compile the package which requires to have certain system dependencies installed, in this case `lblas` and `llapack`. ***This is not the recommended way*** to install R packages on Ubuntu. Instead ***you should install them as [PPAs as described on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu).***

If you insist on compiling the package yourself, install the dependencies via `apt` in the system terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, for pointing out the recommended way. Your solution solved the problem :)

Comment: If you compile all your packages yourself, it will take a long time to install and update them. Also, many packages have various system dependencies such as this, some with even less informative messages and potentially with version conflicts between them. You will be much happier long term if you go for the PPAs